# Product function of elements in a list

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming language and currently I'm having trouble of writing a python function of product on a list.

Given aList = [1,2,3,4,5], we are required to write a python function, "product" to return the product of the items in the list. for example, product(aList[1:3]) would return 24.

I've did research but so far i haven't got it figured out. here is what i came up with but it's wrong.

```
def product(l):
    p = 1
    for i in range(0, len(l)):
        p = p*i
    return p

print(product(aList[1:3])
```

any idea on how i would be able to get the desired output? Also, since I'm relatively new to python, it is not advisable to use built in function such as numpy etc.

Comment: You're multiplying the indices, you need to multiply the elements of the list, not the indices.

Comment: Note that `aList[1:3]` is `[2,3]`, so the product is 6.

Answer (score 3):

Use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with [operator.mul](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
>>> import functools
>>> import operator
>>> functools.reduce(operator.mul, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
120
```

---

In python 2 you can use `reduce` without including `functools` (it was a built in).

You can also replace `operator.mul` with `lambda x,y: x*y`.

Answer (score 2):

No sense using indices if you want to get the values multiplied together. Just iterate over the list directly

```
def product(l):
    p = 1
    for i in l:
        p = p*i
    return p

print(product(aList[1:3]))
```

If, for whatever reason, you need to iterate over the indices, just make sure to use the list item at the given index, rather than the index itself (particularly since you'll start with 0 and get 0 in the end if you go by index)

```
def product(l):
    p = 1
    for i in range(0, len(l)):
        p = p*l[i]
    return p

print(product(aList[1:3]))
```

(also note that you were missing a paren in your print)

Comment: Remember to keep spaces: `p = p * i` or better: `p *= i`

Comment: In most cases, you probably want to use `for i, v in enumerate(l)` to get the index *and* the value while iterating.

Comment: @brianpck Figured it was better to keep the code unchanged except for the specific problem rather than go nitpicking their formatting.

Comment: @brianpck The spacing is strongly encouraged by PEP-8, but not syntactically necessary.

Comment: @chepner Of course, but let's hope we have higher standards than avoiding a `SyntaxError` :) It's just a good thing for a beginner like the OP to know from the start (hence the comment)

Comment: thanks for the help. however, I'm still getting the result of 6 instead of 24. what I've written is exactly the condition the question wants in which aList[1:3] will return 24 which also means that the function is multiplying 2*3*4 inside the list to obtain 24. it still didn't work.

Comment: @chepner could you brief on enumerate? in cases like this where i need to iterate over index and it's value i assume enumerate would help me obtain the desired output of aList[1:3] = 24?

Comment: The product of `alist[1:3]` is *never* going to be 24, because `aList[1:3] == [2,3]`. `enumerate` won't change that; it simply returns a list of tuples consisting of an index and a value. `enumerate(aList[1:3]) == [(1,2), (2,3)]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function to achieve this if you are using Python 2

```
aList = [1,2,3,4,5],
print reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, aList)
```

outputs

```
120
```

Comment: Note that `reduce` is not a built-in for Python3, which the OP appears to be using.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over each element in the list to get the product. Like this:

```
def get_product_of_list(some_list):
    product = 1

    for number in some_list:
        product = product * number

    return product
```

Hope this helps!