# How to multiply all elements of the list to final answer Python numpy not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

Sorry about this. I'm new to Python and am doing a leetcode problem and I am currently trying to multiply all the numbers in the list together to get a final result. Here is my code:

```
import numpy 

class Solution:
    def productExceptSelf(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        arr = []

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp = nums[:i] + nums[i + 1 : len(nums)]
            result = numpy.prod(temp)
            arr.append(result)
        return arr
```

However I get this error:

```
Line 56: Exception: Type <class 'numpy.int64'>: Not implemented
```

Is there any other way to multiply all the elements in a list and storing in a value.

Comment: Which line is line 56?

Comment: Let's see if I can do this via smartphone: `import operator; from functools import reduce; multiply_all = lambda series: reduce(series, operator.__mul__)`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq not too sure since this is in leet code

Comment: Could you please post the complete code?

Comment: I guess you cannot use `numpy` in leetcode.

Comment: @YashGhorpade this is the complete code.

Comment: In a Python session, this code works for a list such as `nums=list(range(1,10))`.  If there are problems using `np.prod`, use one of the answers in: [Product function of elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385336/product-function-of-elements-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the numbers back into an integer:

```
return list(map(int, arr))
```

Or alternatively:

```
arr.append(int(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've ran in Spyder 3.5:

```
import numpy

class Solution:
def productExceptSelf(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    arr = []

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        temp = nums[:i] + nums[i+1 : len(nums)]
        result = numpy.prod(temp)
        arr.append(result)
    return arr

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
solutionObject = Solution()
pES = solutionObject.productExceptSelf(a)
print(pES)
```

This is the output I've got:

```
[5040, 2520, 1680, 1260, 1008, 840, 720]
```

The code works perfectly fine with Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Pranav's answer I ran your code with a random generated list and it worked successfully. Note that when the list exceeds 37 items then numpy.prod() will begin to fail and return 0 as the calculation has now exceeded the data type limit size. You can get pretty big pretty quickly using numpy.prod().
Looking at the error double check your list items are integers or floats.

```
import numpy 
import random

class Solution:
    def productExceptSelf(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        arr = []

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp = nums[:i] + nums[i + 1 : len(nums)]
            result = numpy.prod(temp)
            arr.append(result)
        return arr

x = random.sample(range(0,100), 37)
answer = Solution()
product = answer.productExceptSelf(x)
print(product)
```

Could you provide us with the list that you are using when testing the function? That will help with reproducing your error.